# A continuous function on a closed subset of real line can be continuously extended

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

I need help with this question as I'm not sure Let $f$ be a continuous function on $K$ which is closed in the real line. Show that there exists a continuous $F$ on all of $R$ such that $F(x)=f(x)$ on $K$.

So I'm not sure which theorem to use in Folland to prove this.
If anyone can hint on what to do, I'd be grateful.

Comment: is there a reason for the downvote?

Comment: @Giovanni, if I had to guess, I'd guess lack of shown effort, or not relevant title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Tietze's extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem) because the real line is normal. Alternatively you could consider the connected components of the complement of $K$, these are all open intervals of the form $(-\infty, b)$, $(a,\infty)$ or $(a,b)$ and define $F$ in each interval accordingly.

Comment: I dont see how we can write the complement of K as union or intersection of the sets you listed.

Comment: The complement is open. You can show that any open set can be written as a countable union of open intervals.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Tietze extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem), which says: any continuous function on a the closed subset of a normal space can be extended to the entire space. A normal space is one in which every pair of disjoint closed sets can be separated by a pair of disjoint open sets. The reals are a normal space, a fact which isn't hard to prove and is easy to find a proof of.

Comment: Are there other ways of solving this using only measure theoretic type arguments? Or is measure theory and topology so connected

Comment: I'd say no: it's a purely topological question.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Mice Elf because the theorem applies to continuous functions on the closed subsets of the normal space $\mathbb{R}$. I wasn't aware that link-only answers are forbidden, even when they point to absolutely the right tool. i don't want to argue the point.

Comment: @Shailesh Unless it's vandalized, it's unlikely the wikipedia page for the Tietze extension theorem will come to contain a false proof. But again, i don't want to argue the point.

Comment: @Mice Elf Fair enough. I'll emend my answer.